# .NET Core or .NET Framework for interacting with SOAP Service?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, soap, .net-core

I've been doing some research for hours now and I can't seem to find a clear answer  about this.

The task I'm assigned to needs me to interact with a SOAP service. I basically need to make a web app that interacts with it (sends stuff to it and then requests some more etc).

Before I started I tried to find as much as I could. Never did I find the answer to my question. Which one is better for interacting with SOAP?

.NET Framework or Core? Or even something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both can do this. In Framework add the SOAP web reference by right clicking "References" then "Add Service Reference" > "Advanced" > Add Web Reference.

In Core add the SOAP web reference by right clicking Dependencies and selecting "Add connected service" then choosing "Windows WCF Web Service Reference Provider".

Both of these options will interrogate the WSDL for you and generate the necessary client code to call the service.

Comment: Are there any distinct pros and cons? I'd rather use Core as it's more 'recent' but I want to know if I'm going to bash my head against my pc because of that choice.

Comment: It really depends on what else you want to do. Framework is more mature obviously but I've found many new API's have better support now in Core. If you're starting from scratch and you're web app won't need to do anything particularly unusual I'd probably opt for Core in your position.

Comment: I was thinking the same but I want a second opinion. The web app is supposed to be retrieving a list of campaigns from adobe campaign and then after people choose some stuff (like campaign id etc) will trigger the campaign launch. Net Core it is I guess?

Comment: I have recently implemented a web service that interacts with a Soap Service in .NET Core. Had some issues when I needed to use SWA (Soap With Attachments) but in the end I was also able to solve that. It is more a personal choice in the end.

Comment: @maracuja-juice Thanks man, I appreciate the time.I'm leaning towards Core, too, thanks to you guys.

Comment: One of the only differences I have found is that you need to do the configuration with the different bindings via code.